# Show that the equation $x^3+3x+1=0$ has exactly one real solution

Tags: calculus, cubics

> Show that $x^3+3x+1=0$ has exactly one real solution.

Comment: Can you show some of your progress? Do you have shown the existence of one solution?

Comment: Wat happens when you take the limits $x\rightarrow \pm \infty$? Is the function continuous?

Comment: No i couldn't get it right if u know plz help me out

Comment: Did you cover Rolle's theorem in your lecture?

Comment: Use my comment to show the existence of a root and use the answer below to show that there is only one root.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove using Rolle's Theorem that an equation has exactly one real solution.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/575504/prove-using-rolles-theorem-that-an-equation-has-exactly-one-real-solution)

Comment: Also look into [Descarte's Rule of Signs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs).

Comment: $f(x)=x^3+3x+1$ cannot have a positive real root and has atmost one negative real root (by Descarte's rule of signs). Since complex occur in pair, so one root has to be real.

Comment: If the coefficients are all positive real values then it must have only one real root for any cubic equation.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: use Calculus. Note that derivative always takes positive value.

Comment: I downvoted this. In my opinion you missed explaining key points. You should explain the significance of obtaining a positive derivative. It indicates that the slope of the curve is always increasing, and that it can cut the x-axis at only one point, hence it can have only one real root.

Comment: @ Aksshar Gandhi.  Quite often some answers posted here are hints (and I had clearly marked it as hint).

Answer (score 0):

The [discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#The_discriminant) is

$$\Delta = - 4 \cdot 3^3 - 27 = - 5 \cdot 27 < 0$$

From the negativity of $\Delta$, we conclude that the cubic polynomial has **only one** real root.

Answer (score 0):

A general method would be to check value of polynomial at Maxima and minima (Wiggles). If both values have same sign then only one real root. If no Wiggles then too single root.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f$ defined by $f(x)=x^3+3x+1$.
we know there is at least one real root.

assume there are $2$ real roots
$a$ and $b$.

the polynomial function $f$ is continuous at $[a,b]$ and has a derivative in $(a,b)$.

Role's Theorem allows us to say
there exists $c\in(a,b)$ such that

$f'(c)=3c^2+3=0$ which is not possible.

so there is only one real root.

Comment: This si exactly the solution of the duplicate.