# Using Rolle's Theorem to prove roots.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, roots, rolles-theorem

> Show that $x^5+10x+3=0$ has exactly one real solution using Rolle's Theorem.

I am referencing a closely related stack answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/575504/prove-using-rolles-theorem-that-an-equation-has-exactly-one-real-solution). 
So I have tried letting $y=x^5+10x+3$.
Then $y'=5x^4+10$. Set $y'=0$
$$0=5x^4+10$$
$f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ and $f$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$ but I need a closed interval $[a.b]$ of continuity that corresponds to an open interval $(a,b)$ of differentiation. Where $f(a)=f(b)$.

I do not see any real solution such as they were able to find in the provided link. As well as I do not see how to satisfy $f(a)=f(b)$. Any help and explanation is appreciated!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assume $f(x)=x^5+10x+3$ has two solutions $f(a)=f(b)=0, \space a<b$, then according to [Rolle's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle's_theorem) $\exists c \in (a,b): f'(c)=0$. But $f'(x)=5x^4+10>0$ and has no solutions, contradiction. At this point, we know that $f(x)$ has $1$ or $0$ solutions.

Using [Intermediate value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem) $f(-1)=-8$ and $f(0)=3$, thus $\exists c \in (-1,0): f(c)=0$.

Combining these two facts, $f(x)$ has exactly one solution.

Comment: So there is no solutions?

Comment: No, you can use the Intermediate value theorem to show that indeed, there is one solution.  @rtybase simply has shown that there exists, at most, one solution in the reals.

Comment: @NickPavini there is exactly one ... I updated my answer.

Comment: Okay...it seems rtybase edited to answer your qurestion, Nick.

Comment: One last question. Assuming this is correct why do we even need Rolle's Theorem?

Comment: The question asks to prove for "exactly one real solution".  Intermediate value theorem tells us there exists a solution (one or more). Using Rolle's theorem reveals it's exactly one.

Comment: @rtybase very nice answer!(+1 especially for the last comment!)

Comment: When f'(x) has no real root, on what basis you concluded that f has exactly 1 real root?

Comment: @NoChance $f(x)$ is polynomial of degree 5. As per the **Intermediate value theorem**, it has **at least one** root. If we assume $f(x)$ has 2 roots, we obtain a contradiction. So, the conclusion is?

Comment: Got it - Thanks

Answer (score 2):

$f'(x)=5x^4+10\geq 10>0$ for all real $x.$ So $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ is one-to-one.

Because  if $f(a)=f(b)$ with $a<b$ then the function  $g(x)=f(x)-f(a)=f(x)-f(b)$ is $0$ at $x=a$ and at $x=b$, implying $g'(x)=0$ for some $x\in (a,b)$ by Rolle's theorem. But $g'(x)=f'(x)\ne 0$ for all $x$.

Therefore there is at most one real $x$ with $f(x)=0.$

Since $f(0)>0$ and $f(-2)<0$ and $f$ is continuous we have $0\in [f(-2),f(0)]\subset \{f(x):x\in [-2,0]\} $.

Therefore there is at least one real $x$ with $f(x)=0. $

Answer (score 1):

Slight variation with fewer calculations: After you use Rolle's theorem, it suffices to note that a root exists, since 
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}f(x)=+\infty
$$
and
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty}f(x)=-\infty
$$
Since polynomials are continuous, there is at least one root.

Note: This shows any odd degree polynomial has a real root!